# MySQL InnoDB Backup: are dump files enough?

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, server-crashes, dump

What exactly does the default `ibdata1` file store that does not exist in a `mysqldump`?

I've got a backup/rsync job that stores dump files of a MySQL 5.5 database on a remote server for rotating daily/weekly backups.

However, I am not currently backing up the `ibdata1` file itself -- is this a nightmare waiting to happen or are dump files enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are doing proper mysqldumps the information necessary to rebuild the database will be present.  You don't have to backup the ibdata1 file.

Comment: Proper mysqldumps are comprised of SQL code and all the data necessary to recreate all the tables and their relationships in the database they were made from.